# need help to apply hover effect for footer

Tags: html, css, hover, footer

I have a footer with 100% width and a background color of black. the height of it is around 60px, it has a little bit of text. Vve made it so it has an opacity of (0.1), what i want to do which is not working is when i hover somewhere over the footer i want it the opacity back to default (1.0), but it doesnt let me do it.

HTML

```
<footer>
    <p>Linnéuniversitetet, Webbteknik 1</p>
    <p class="created">Created by DK222CU</p>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    opacity:.1;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}

footer p {
    float:left;
    margin-left:8%;
}

.created {
    margin-right:8%;
    float:right;
}

footer :hover {
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

Comment: `:hover` is a psuedo-class, so it needs to read as `footer:hover` without the space that you have before `:hover`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just get rid of the space in `footer :hover`

So you'll have:

```
footer:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

And here's your working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksauu1z3/

Comment: Ehmm im so dumb, Thanks for pointing that little mistake out :)